# finding the Branch points of a logarithmic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the branch points of $f(z)=log(1+z^{1/3})$.

**My approach**

I can clearly see that for $z^{1/3}$, $z=0$ is the branch point and if we let $z=\frac{1}{t}$, then $z=\infty$ is also a branch point as $t=0$ is the branch point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

When is $1+z^{1/3}=0$?

Recall that $w=0$ is a branch point for $\log w$.

Comment: You mean to say all the solutions of $1+z^{1/3} =0$?

Comment: yes, I mean that.